# Origem da expressão "de mala e cuia"

Tags: expressões, origem, regionalismo

Sou gaúcho (do Rio Grande do Sul - Brasil) e a expressão **de mala e cuia** é muito utlizada no estado com o significado: **ir embora de forma definitiva**.

[image]

Sempre achei que era uma expressão regionalista, principalmente por que **cuia** é algo usado para tomar chimarrão (bebida típica do estado) até encontrar essa notícia em um sitio português: [A piña colada, o discurso de Kennedy e a cama de John e Yoko: 100 anos de Hilton, 100 anos de História](https://observador.pt/especiais/a-pina-colada-o-discurso-de-kennedy-e-a-cama-de-john-e-yoko-100-anos-de-hilton-100-anos-de-historia/)

> Conrad Hilton chegou ao Texas em 1919 disposto a comprar um banco.
>   Acabou por investir num hotel, o primeiro de uma cadeia espalhada pelo
>   mundo onde a História se instalou **de mala e cuia**.

Então, isso é realmente usada em Portugal? E a origem ainda é no Rio Grande do Sul?

Comment: Nunca vi ou ouvi esta expressão antes, cá em Portugal, nem sabia sequer o que era uma cuia. O Priberam [indica](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cuia) ser um termo brasileiro, e o meu corretor ortográfico indica a palavra *cuia* como um erro. Aliás, a árvore de cujos frutos se fazem as cuias [é originária do Brasil](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Cuitezeira).

Comment: Nos comentários da noticia, há até um pessoa perguntando o que significa cuia! Bom, eu vi o perfil da jornalista e enviei um email para ela. Com sorte, ela nos responde. Quem sabe, é gaucha! :)

Comment: Ela me respondeu e disse q também é utilizada em Portugal, mas em desuso. Eu também achei isso -> https://origemdapalavra.com.br/pergunta/pergunta-9703/, a cuia também é utilzada para guardar grãos e água. A palavra cabaça (q é sinonimo de cuia) é de origem árabe.

Comment: Mas uma cabaça é feita do fruto de uma planta [da família das abóboras](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caba%C3%A7a), não devia ser sinónimo... mas ah, bom. Estamos sempre a aprender. :)

Comment: Aqui no Nordeste, as cabaças (também chamada de cuia) serve para pôr água, servir de colher (em casas de farinhas, por exemplo) etc. Há uma música do cantor Flávio Leandro que possui o mesmo significado que "ir/chegar definitivamente". `Pode vir de mala e cuia, amor / Que eu não vou tá nem aí pro povo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A expressão *mala e cuia* é quase certamente de origem brasileira; o significado que referes (*mudar-se* definitivamente) parece ainda ser relativamente recente — uma edição da revista municipal de São Paulo, que o Google Books data de 1937 (mas que possivelmente é anterior) define [*viajar de mala e cuia* como ***viajar sem bagagem***](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qgPOAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22mala+e+cuia%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22mala+e+cuia%22). A referência mais antiga no Google Books é 1924, num guia que refere existir uma cadeia de restaurantes de comida mineira com esse nome. Só na década de 1960 começam a surgir ocorrências da expressão cujo valor é inequivocamente *(mudar-se) de forma definitiva*, ainda a par do significado *sem bagagem*.

A *Grande Enciclopédia Portuguesa e Brasileira*, publicada entre 1936 e 1960 e bastante exaustiva, também não refere esta expressão. A entrada para *cuia* lê:

> *s. f.* Fruto da cuieira (v.), com cuja casca de fazem vasilhas do mesmo nome e aplicadas a vários misters: «voltou logo trazendo pães, postas de peixe frito e uma *cuia* com farinha», Franklin Távora, *O Cabeleira*, cap. 11, p. 155. ◆ Vasilha de feitio e usos semelhantes: chama-se *cuia* no Rio-Grande-do-Sul ao recipiente em que se prepara e toma o mate. ◆ Espécie de almofada de cabelo postiço com que as senhoras enfeitavam a nunca e as costas: «no toutiço dentro da rêde a *cuia*, figurando uma trança enrolada, caída até às costas», Ricardo Jorge, *Canhenho dum Vagamundo*, p. 204. ◆ *Bras.* O mesmo que *cuité*. ◆ *Bras. de Pernamb.* Medida de capacidade para secos equivalente a 1/32 de alqueire. (Cf. Rodolfo Garcia, *Dic. de Brasileirismos*, s. v.). ◆ *Bras. Gír.* Cabeça. *Levar, apanhar na cuia*, apanhar pancada ficar vencido. *Meter a cuia*, dar cabeçadas. *Banzé de cuia*, conflito, confusão, rôlo. (Cf. Raúl Pederneiras, *Geringonça Carioca*, s. v.). ◆ Prato da balança. ◆ *Prov. beir. e trasm.* O mesmo que *cu*.
>
> BOT. Fruto da *cuieira* (v.).  ◆ **Cuia de macaco :** Nome vulgar brasileiro da *Couroupita lentula* Miers. e da *C. subsessilis* Pilg., árvores da família das lecitidóideas, a segunda também designada no Pará *castanha de macaco*. ◆ **Cuia do brejo :** Designação brasileira do *Styrax camporum* Pohl, árvore da família das estiracáceas, boa para arruamentos e que produz uma resina semelhante ao benjoim. Possui também os nomes de *canela poca*, *estoraque do campo* e *pinduíba*.

O significado de *cuia* como fruto da cuieira não está naturalmente limitado ao Brasil, mas a árvore é nativa da América do Sul, pelo que o seu uso em Portugal tenderá a ser limitado. O significado como *vasilha* também não tem essa anotação na *Grande Enciclopédia*, mas tem-no no Priberam — e eu também não encontro exemplos desse uso em Portugal. Ricardo d'Almeida Jorge é um autor português, mas a aceção de *cuia* em que é citado não parece ter qualquer relação com fruto da cuieira/vasilha.

Dito isto, é verdade que a expressão *de mala e cuia*, com o seu significado moderno, aparece em alguns textos portugueses. Por exemplo, também [aqui](https://inverno.blogs.sapo.pt/ingenuidade-160593):

> Talvez a moça não perceba que; antes de se mudar para cá *de mala e cuia*, já Portugal andava pelas "bocas do mundo", salvo seja, no melhorzinho que as línguas têm para dizer, sobre este belo jardim.

Mas trata-se certamente de importação da expressão brasileira, que será compreendida por uma fração dos portugueses.

Comment: Eu sempre entendi a expressão como "como toda a bagagem" ou " com todos os pertences".  Dizer que alguém chegou "de mala e cuia", **para mim** significa que chegou com muita bagagem, e que provavelmente não vai ficar poucos dias.  É como eu sempre entendi a expressão.

Comment: @Centaurus no google books já há alguns exemplos com esse significado na década de 60, mas ainda se encontra p.ex. este de 1962: _Mas eu tinha um recurso: descer de mala e cuia entre os Kuben Kran Ken e lá ficar uma ou duas semanas, aguardando que um próximo "Bete" viesse me buscar._

Comment: as vezes, falamos no sul: mas tu veio de mala e cuia.... apenas para siginifcar que a pessoa trouxe mais que o necessário, mas não que vai ficar definitivo. Realmente, não siginifca se mudar de forma definitiva, mas no meu entender, trazer mais que o necessário pelo tempo planejado de estadia.

Comment: O uso que conheço coincide com o do Centaurus: muita ou toda bagagem, podendo também denotar excesso, como menciona o Peixoto, mas não necessariamente mudança permanente.

Answer (score 1):

"Mala e cuia" - Expressão que caracteriza o viajante nordestino que usava a cuia como recipiente para beber ou para apanhar água no banho durante suas viagens. Ele deixava tudo para trás e só levava mala e isso quando tinha e a cuia, indispensável.